# как реагировать на inline кнопки php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Я создал кнопку которая отправляется вместе с сообщением, теперь мне нужно чтобы после ее нажатия отправилось сообщение, например "введите количество", а после него пользователь вводил бы сообщение, которое в процессе бы обработалось.

К сожалению у меня никак не выходит обработать нажатие на inline кнопку, чего не хватает?

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
    file_put_contents('file.txt', '$data: '.print_r($data, 1)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    define('TOKEN', '5987948599:AAF-A6Gfn-oMEj1e6sdf5eaK0kmMFQ0NrPY');

    if ($data['callback_query']) {
        switch ($data['callback_query']['data']) {
            case 'kol':
                //тут хочу запросить данные для ввода у пользователя
            break;
        }
    } else {
        $data = $data['message'];
        $message = mb_strtolower(($data['text'] ? $data['text'] : $data['data']), 'utf-8');

        switch ($message) {
            case 'действия':
            $method = 'sendMessage';

            $send_data = [
                'text' => "какое действие вы хотите совершить?",
                'reply_markup' => [
                    'inline_keyboard' => [
                            [
                                [
                                    'text' => 'вписать количество',
                                    'callback_data' => 'kol'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                ]]; 
             break;
        }
    }

    $send_data['chat_id'] = $data['chat'] ['id'];
    $res = sendTelegram($method, $send_data);

    function sendTelegram($method, $data, $headers = [])
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/' . $method,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array_merge(array("Content-Type: application/json"))
        ]);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return (json_decode($result, 1) ? json_decode($result, 1) : $result);
    }
?>
```